# Misunderstanding of how links work in lists

Tags: python, list

Why does `x[0].append(4)` affects on y[0]?

```py
from copy import copy

x = [[1], [2]]
y = copy(x)
x.append([3])
x[0].append(4)

print(x)
print(y)
```

```
>>> [[1, 4], [2], [3]]
>>> [[1, 4], [2]]
```

Comment: because its a shallow copy and not deep copy,  so only outer most list will be copied and the inner references will be passed as is
https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/copy-python-deep-copy-shallow-copy/

Comment: @saurabhbaid, I want to find out why deepcopy will change something

Comment: @saurabhbaid, I've got it, thank you